# AdSense status still asking to setup ads on site

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense

I have registered to AdSense and added the ads to the website thru the WordPress AdSense plug in. But when I go to my AdSense account, its still saying :

> Your account is getting reviewed. Help us finish the review by setting
>   up ads on your site.
>   [image]

Do I have to wait before I see the red bar that says my account is under review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an ad unit, you'll see HTML code that you need to copy and paste into your website. I'm not too familiar with wordpress, but I'm sure you can use a plugin or something that allows you to directly insert HTML into your website. You can insert adsense code there. Just make sure its inserted in such a way where it does not violate adsense policies.

Once you done that, test your page. The first few times the page is loaded, you might get a box containing your browser message that states the page could not be loaded instead of an ad. This is normal until either some time has passed and/or enough visitors visited the site. You know you're doing well when you actually see an advertisement, especially if the advertisement is on-topic with your site.

Comment: thank you, yes i did use a plug-in to insert the ad from AdSense, but all I see from the site are blank spaces on where the ads should be. @Mike

Comment: If the size of those blank spaces are roughly the size of the ad unit you're trying to use, then its possible that google has not updated their records. You could also run the page through webpagetest.org and see if one of the elements being loaded is from google. The URL to look for on webpagetest.org waterfall detailed results is the URL in the script tags in the adsense code google gave you.

Comment: okay i saw something like this `http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js` does that mean ads are already on my site? @Mike

Comment: If you saw that URL listed when testing with webpagetest.org, it means you put the adsense code on correctly and that google should be at the stage to review your website. I'd give google a few days and if that doesn't help, review adsense policies to see that you comply.